# Implementação de um sistema no servidor

Tags: mysql, servidor-de-aplicação

Tenho que instalar uma aplicação java cujo o banco de dados fica no servidor.

Porém tenho duvidas sobre o processo, através de pesquisas, conclui que tenho que apenas instalar o MYSql no servidor, e na conexão do meu sistema setar o IP com o IP do servidor, porém a minha duvida é a seguinte, qual ferramenta tenho que instalar no servidor para colocar o meu banco de dados ? o processo é o mesmo que eu descrevi (mudar o ip e etc) ?

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao site StackOverOflow. As perguntas devem ser sobre um problema específico de programação, um algoritmo de software. Para um maior entendimento, consulte [Central de ajuda > Perguntando](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Normalmente o seu provedor de hospedagem já instala o MySql automáticamente para você e disponibiliza um painel de controle para o seu domínio onde você pode criar o banco de dados.
Após criar o banco de dados você informa o IP do seu servidor, nome do banco de dados que você criou, nome do usuário do banco de dados e a senha de acesso ao banco( estas são as chamadas credenciais, que você irá escolher/informar no momento da criação do Banco de dados no servidor).